# Github is inaccessible in india today

Tags: github

I tried to access github today and i was getting the "Your connection is not private" error message.
I was not to able to take a pull or push to a repo. But i was able to checkout to other branches because that branch was created on my local. 
I tried to change the name server settings of chrome and got a message that it is taken from ths system settings.

Comment: FYI: http://www.zdnet.com/article/india-blocks-32-websites-including-github-internet-archive-pastebin-vimeo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name server on ubuntu to google DNS helped my out.

Google DNS servers are 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Here's how to change.   Edit resolv.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and type <kbd>wq!</kbd> and edit the entries. Github should be accessible